compiler complains that an unused variable is used when simply a cast to void is performed
We just found out that a certain compiler (Greenhills) sees the following construct as an error:
// local variable
mytype x;
...
((void) (x));

The compiler reports:
error #549-D: variable "x" is used before its value is set.
We're using such constructs in special situations to avoid compiler warnings related to variables not being used at all. We want to test if the type really exists so this is totally intended.
My question is however related to how this compiler behaves. According to what C standard rule does the compiler decide that a cast to void (which should literally translate to nothing in assembler code) is actually "using" the variable?

This looks like a compiler bug to me.

Perhaps you can initialize the variable to work around the warning?

The C standard C17 6.3.2.2. says this:

The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has type void) shall not
be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be
applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void
expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its
side effects.)

So most of the time the expression is simply not used. However the last sentence in parenthesis is interesting - evaluated for side effects means for example if you have a function as operand, that function will get executed. Or in case you have a volatile qualified variable, the compiler must evaluate that expression. It has always been muddy whether (void)my_volatile; should be treated as a read access or not.
What we can say for sure is that if mytype doesn't involve volatile then the compiler is confused and should just discard the whole line. But if it is volatile then that probably involves a read access.
However the compiler still shouldn't make any assumptions about if a volatile is initialized or not, because the very definition of volatile is that the variable may change at any time beyond the compiler's control. So it would still be an incorrect diagnostic message.
I would report this as a compiler diagnostics bug since cast to void is a common C idiom.

In upcoming C23 you'll be able to declare the variable as [[maybe_unused]] mytype x; and that too should silence compiler warnings.


My question is however related to how this compiler behaves. According to what C standard rule does the compiler decide that a cast to void (which should literally translate to nothing in assembler code) is actually "using" the variable?

C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 says:

Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion…

In ((void) (x)), x (and (x)) is not the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, or the -- operator and is not the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator. Therefore it is converted to the value stored in x. This is an access to x.
The fact that (x) is cast to (void) and used in a statement expression means the value is discarded, per C 2018 6.3.2.2 1 and 6.8.3 2. These rules do not negate the lvalue conversion described above; the value of x is accessed and then discarded.
These rules are on the level of the abstract machine the C standard uses to specify semantics. The rules in 5.1.2.3 6, about observable behavior, allow a compiler to optimize the program so that the access is not physically performed. So a compiler is not required to physically implement the access to x. It is also allowed to physically implement the access; both behaviors conform to the C standard.
Some compilers take (void) x; as an indication that it is intentional that x may not be used and otherwise ignore such as a statement. This interpretation is not required by the C standard. It appears your compiler does not do that and is interpreting the statement literally as a read of x followed by a discarding of the value. This may simply be low quality compiler implementation rather than an outright bug.
The compiler is allowed to issue a warning message for this because no rule in the C standard prohibits a compiler from issuing diagnostic messages beyond what the C standard requires. Note 9 in 5.1.1.3 1 says:

… Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostic messages, often referred to as warnings, as long as a valid program is still correctly translated…

